# Error in using 'psql' from osm2po

Tags: postgresql

I am following this direction to make network dataset from OSM data to use ArcGIS network analysis (by using osm2po and psql)(http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/loadingdata.html).
So far so good except errors in using 'psql'
Please see below message:

psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user “postgres”

It asked to type password so I typed my password but it didn't work (also it didn't show my password. That is, the password what I typed is invisible).

Please let me know what the problem is.

Also, is there any way to load .sql data into postgreSQL by not using commond line?

Comment: There's a number of problems here. First, there's no clear GIS component to this question.  Second, you've got multiple questions. And third, you appear to be using the administrative user 'postgresql' for data loading, which is a dangerous practice, likely to result in damage to your database instance (instead, create a new login, user, and schema to own data, and a new tablespace for the data to reside)

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behaviour that psql don't show password being typed.

Do please try typing your password again - be sure you're entering the same password you use when you were setting up PostgreSQL.

Remember that dialog?:

[image: Postgres server connection]

You can load your data using pgAdmin (of course there you'll also be asked for your connection credentials). 
Just doubleclick your database server, then doubleclick your database and then run the SQL tool (number 1. -> enclosed ilustration):

2. Open your sql file - that's normal explorer dialog
3. Run file - postgres will process everything.

[image: pgAdmin SQL tool]